# iPhone App Windows Development and TSQL Solutions

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, xcode, t-sql

I've been asked to develop a simple app that allows the user to enter some information, hit a button, then it will do a look up on our Microsoft `SQL` Database and return the results to display to the user. However, I have some limitations.

For one, I'm on Windows 7 computer. This means Xcode isn't a viable option. I could possibly acquire a mac within the office, but that's a bit iffy at this time. Secondly, I understand from what I've researched that Xcode doesn't have any viable options for looking up data in Microsoft `SQL`. Closest I saw was using `SOAP`. Last problem is that I need to deploy onto my own phone for demonstration purposes and any apps developed will only be for in house use.

So, what options should I be looking at to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

**You have to get a mac.** Then install **Xcode** and start development. There is a library you can use for accessing the `MS SQL` database. It's name is `SQLClient`. You can find it [**here**](http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/an-open-source-sql-server-library-for-ios/).